# Thinking symfony relationship for set

Tags: symfony, set, many-to-many, relationship, favorites

I have 2 entity product (sigle product: id, name, category and set: id, name). Set is compose with one or more product. I add relation ManyToMany between product and set. Symfony add entity set_product.
I want in product add « product preferential » (of set_product) in case the product is a set.
I don’t know if thinking is correct ? What is the good way ? Thank in advance.

Answer (score 0):

First, if only set is composed by one or more product, you should use OneToMany (set can have one or more product).

I think your thinking with product preferential should work anyway.

Comment: I wanted to add relation at product and to the question What class should this entity be related to? SetProduct -> error [ERROR] Unknown class "SetProduct"